# Transverse a single point

Tags: differential-topology

I got very confused with understanding this theorem. So $\{y\}$ is a point, how could it be transversed by $f$?

[image]

Proof: Given any $y \in Y.$ alter $f$ homotopically to make it transversal to $\{y\}$.

Thank you for your help~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tangent space to a point is trivial, so to say that $f$ is transverse to $\{y\}$ is just to say that $y$ is a regular value of $f$, i.e. that $f'(x):T_xX\to T_yY$ is surjective for all $x\in f^{-1}(y)$.

Comment: Aha! So that's just the image of $df_x$ needs to equal to $T_yY$. That is to say $\{y\}$ is a regular value! Thanks a lot Zev!

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)

Comment: So I guess when $f$ does not pass through $y$, it is transversal and $I_2(f,\{y\}) = 0$; when $f$ pass through $y$, it is transversal when $y$ is a regular value, and $I_2(f,\{y\}) = 1$  right? Then, how come $I_2(f,\{y\})$ is the same for all $y \in Y$? (I'm happy to open a new question for this if you think that is better, and thanks in advance!)

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by $I_2$?

Comment: Thanks a lot Zev! $I_2(f,Z)$ is the mod 2 intersection number of the map $f$.

Comment: Oh, it is the number of points $f^{-1}(Z)$ modulo 2.

Comment: Then it makes sense to me.. But why it has to do with transversality - just use the strong condition of transversality to show $y$ is a regular value...?

Comment: @Jellyfish: It's the same for all $y$ because $Y$ is connected and the number is *locally constant* by the Stack of Records Theorem. G&P use the transversality language so that this is defined even when $y$ is not a regular value by making a small wiggle of the map.

Comment: Oh, got it. I know the locally constant by the stack of records theorem implies globally constant for connected space, but  thanks so much @TedShifrin for clearing that $y$ can be wiggled into transversality. =)